# Windows .inf files: how do I set the default Network Connection name during network driver install?

Tags: windows, winapi, installation, driver, wdk

I'm trying to adapt the open source [TAP-Win32 driver](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/browser/tap-win32/i386/OemWin2k.inf.in) for my project.

When it installs (at least on Windows 7, and I think Windows XP too) it creates a device named "TAP-Win32 Adapter V9" in the Devices control panel.  This is easy to change by editing the [OemWin2k.inf file that comes with it](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/browser/tap-win32/i386/OemWin2k.inf.in).

However, the device then gets attached to a network in the Windows Networks browser, where it is named by default something like "Local Area Connection 2."  I can easily rename this using the GUI: just click on the network and press F2.

But my problem is this: the network device I'm working on is definitely not a "Local Area Connection", it's actually a virtual network device.  What can I do to make the name *by default* show up using a more descriptive name of my choosing?

Is there any general documentation about this I should be reading?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the script attached [here](http://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/TapRenameScript), it's from Open VPN community and I use it after installation to make everything a little bit nicer.